# Client Coordinates to server code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, geolocation

Iæm writing an web apllication that retrieves user coordinates, and check weather forecast and give back effective temperature. All this need to be done in one click.

What I have done so far: Use Javascript to get location and get forecast for this location. My problem is that that I don't find any way to get the JS coordinates back to server codebehind in Page_load. I've seen lot of guides where they use a button to use the coordinates after Page_load. But that is not an option for me.

The problem is that javascript seems to be done after every page_events. So I don't have any way to use the location before the page is finished loading. Even if I pass the coordinates to textboxes.

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="getCord">

    if(typeof navigator.geolocation === 'undefined')
    {
        alert("Geolocation services are not supported by your web browser");
    }

    else
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleLocation, handleError);
    }

    function handleLocation(position)
    {

        var lat = position.coords.latitude;

        document.getElementById('<%= latTextBox.ClientID %>').value = lat;

        var lon = position.coords.longitude;

        document.getElementById('<%= lonTextBox.ClientID %>').value = lon;

    }

    function handleError(error)
    {
        switch (error.code) 
        {
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                alert('Timeout');
            break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                alert('Position unavailable');
            break;
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                alert('Permission denied');
            break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                alert('Unknown error');
            break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here's my codebehind:

```
    private string lat = "63.4164148";
    private string lon = "10.409051999999999";
    private string xmlData = "";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(!lonTextBox.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            lon = lonTextBox.Text;
        }

        if(!latTextBox.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            lat = latTextBox.Text;
        }

        maps.HRef = "maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:" + lat + "+" + lon;

        loadXML();

    }
```

I've searched over a week for an answer to this, so I hope I don't get some simple links to a well known site who explains this.

Comment: JavaScript will run each time the page is posted back, after the server side has finished sending the content to the client. That's just how the ASP.NET postback model works. I suggest you figure out what needs to happen on the server side and what needs to happen on the client side so you get a decent separation of concerns.

Comment: That was a very good relevation. Is there any way to use the HTML5 Geolocation before the page is finished loading? Or to put it in another way, use the Location data before application do its first postback?

Comment: So if the javascript is runned after postback, can I make the postback end with postback, so i can use the coordinates in Page_load?

Comment: I would change the architecture a little bit. Move critical services so that they can be called by AJAX (put the services into [ASMX Web service files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308359)). Then call those web service functions with JavaScript and AJAX ([jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) makes this easier) after you've gotten the location via HTML5.

Comment: If I understand you right, I should put the codebehind methods in a webservice file, then call them in the javascript file? And this web service should be called, using jquery.ajax?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.